# Multi-threaded async web service call in c# .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous

I have 2 ASP.net 3.5 asmx web services, **ws2** and **ws3**. They contain operations **op21** and **op31** respectively. op21 sleeps for **2 seconds** and op31 sleeps for **3 seconds**. I want to call both op21 and op31 from **op11** in a web service, **ws1**, asynchronously. Such that when I call **op11** from a client synchronously.,the time-taken will be **3 seconds** which is the total. I currently get **5 seconds** with this code:

```
WS2SoapClient ws2 = new WS2SoapClient();
WS3SoapClient ws3 = new WS3SoapClient();

//capture time
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;            
//make calls

IAsyncResult result1 = ws3.BeginOP31(null,null);
IAsyncResult result2 = ws2.BeginOP21(null,null);
WaitHandle[] handles = { result1.AsyncWaitHandle, result2.AsyncWaitHandle };

WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles);

//calculate time difference
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(now);
return "Asynchronous Execution Time (h:m:s:ms): " + String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}",
ts.Hours,
ts.Minutes,
ts.Seconds,
ts.Milliseconds);
```

The expected result is that the total time for both requests should be equal to the time it takes for the slower request to execute.

Note that this works as expected when I debug it with Visual Studio, however when running this on IIS, the time is 5 seconds which seems to show the requests are not processed concurrently.

My question is, is there a specific configuration with IIS and the ASMX web services that might need to be setup properly for this to work as expected?

Comment: Where are you implementing WSxSoapClient? What thread are you using? I am getting a STA threa is not supported Exception when I try to run your code (replacing your web calls with Action.BeginInvoke).

Comment: What version of .net are you running? Might be a more elegant way of doing this with TPL (.net 4 or above), a lot more readable too.

Comment: @Aron They are auto-generated SOAP clients from adding a service reference. The service was built using c#. Here are the 2 services/operations, both are deployed on localhost/IIS already.

public string OP31()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return "OP31 Done";
        }

public string OP21()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return "OP21 Done";
        }

Comment: @DavidKhaykin .NET 3.5

Comment: Are you testing this on your local machine or server?

Comment: @mariozski local machine IIS

Comment: New update, the asmx is actually yielding the desired result (3 seconds) on IIS. however when i access it from the client webpage, on IIS, synchronously and asynchronously... wrong result (5 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

**Original Answer:**

I tried this with google.com and bing.com am getting the same thing, linear execution. The problem is that you are starting the BeginOP() calls on the same thread, and the AsyncResult (for whatever reason) is not returned until the call is completed. Kind of useless.

My pre-TPL multi-threading is a bit rusty but I tested the code at the end of this answer and it executes asynchronously: This is a .net 3.5 console app. Note I obviously obstructed some of your code but made the classes look the same.

---

**Update:**

I started second-guessing myself because my execution times were so close to each other, it was confusing. So I re-wrote the test a little bit to include both your original code and my suggested code using Thread.Start(). Additionally, I added Thread.Sleep(N) in the WebRequest methods such that it should simulate vastly different execution times for the requests.

The test results do show that the code you posted was sequentially executed as I stated above in my original answer.

[image: Test Results]

Note the total time is much longer in both cases than the actual web request time because of the Thread.Sleep(). I also added the Thread.Sleep() to offset the fact that the first web request to any site takes a long time to spin up (9 seconds), as can be seen above. Either way you slice it, it's clear that the times are sequential in the "old" case and truly "asynchronous" in the new case.

---

**The updated program for testing this out:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace MultiThreadedTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Test both ways of executing IAsyncResult web calls

            ExecuteUsingWaitHandles();
            Console.WriteLine();

            ExecuteUsingThreadStart();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void ExecuteUsingWaitHandles()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting to execute using wait handles (old way) ");

            WS2SoapClient ws2 = new WS2SoapClient();
            WS3SoapClient ws3 = new WS3SoapClient();

            IAsyncResult result1 = null;
            IAsyncResult result2 = null;

            // Time the threadas
            var stopWatchBoth = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            result1 = ws3.BeginOP31();
            result2 = ws2.BeginOP21();

            WaitHandle[] handles = { result1.AsyncWaitHandle, result2.AsyncWaitHandle };
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles);

            stopWatchBoth.Stop();

            // Display execution time of individual calls
            Console.WriteLine((result1.AsyncState as StateObject));
            Console.WriteLine((result2.AsyncState as StateObject));

            // Display time for both calls together
            Console.WriteLine("Asynchronous Execution Time for both is {0}", stopWatchBoth.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        }

        private static void ExecuteUsingThreadStart()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting to execute using thread start (new way) ");

            WS2SoapClient ws2 = new WS2SoapClient();
            WS3SoapClient ws3 = new WS3SoapClient();

            IAsyncResult result1 = null;
            IAsyncResult result2 = null;

            // Create threads to execute the methods asynchronously
            Thread startOp3 = new Thread( () => result1 = ws3.BeginOP31() );
            Thread startOp2 = new Thread( () => result2 = ws2.BeginOP21() );

            // Time the threadas
            var stopWatchBoth = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            // Start the threads
            startOp2.Start();
            startOp3.Start();

            // Make this thread wait until both of those threads are complete
            startOp2.Join();
            startOp3.Join();

            stopWatchBoth.Stop();

            // Display execution time of individual calls
            Console.WriteLine((result1.AsyncState as StateObject));
            Console.WriteLine((result2.AsyncState as StateObject));

            // Display time for both calls together
            Console.WriteLine("Asynchronous Execution Time for both is {0}", stopWatchBoth.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        }
    }

    // Class representing your WS2 client
    internal class WS2SoapClient : TestWebRequestAsyncBase
    {
        public WS2SoapClient() : base("http://www.msn.com/") { }

        public IAsyncResult BeginOP21()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10D));
            return BeginWebRequest();
        }
    }

    // Class representing your WS3 client
    internal class WS3SoapClient : TestWebRequestAsyncBase
    {
        public WS3SoapClient() : base("http://www.google.com/") { }

        public IAsyncResult BeginOP31()
        {
            // Added sleep here to simulate a much longer request, which should make it obvious if the times are overlapping or sequential
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20D)); 
            return BeginWebRequest();
        }
    }

    // Base class that makes the web request
    internal abstract class TestWebRequestAsyncBase
    {
        public StateObject AsyncStateObject;
        protected string UriToCall;

        public TestWebRequestAsyncBase(string uri)
        {
            AsyncStateObject = new StateObject()
            {
                UriToCall = uri
            };

            this.UriToCall = uri;
        }

        protected IAsyncResult BeginWebRequest()
        {
            WebRequest request =
               WebRequest.Create(this.UriToCall);

            AsyncCallback callBack = new AsyncCallback(onCompleted);

            AsyncStateObject.WebRequest = request;
            AsyncStateObject.Stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            return request.BeginGetResponse(callBack, AsyncStateObject);
        }

        void onCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            this.AsyncStateObject = (StateObject)result.AsyncState;
            this.AsyncStateObject.Stopwatch.Stop();

            var webResponse = this.AsyncStateObject.WebRequest.EndGetResponse(result);
            Console.WriteLine(webResponse.ContentType, webResponse.ResponseUri);
        }
    }

    // Keep stopwatch on state object for illustration of individual execution time
    internal class StateObject
    {
        public System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch Stopwatch { get; set; }
        public WebRequest WebRequest { get; set; }
        public string UriToCall;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Request to {0} executed in {1} seconds", this.UriToCall, Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling sleep in your BeginOP31 method on the client which means that it will execute inline. This is normal because async IO does not just mean that it is called on another thread (there are no threads involved). The sleep should be *on the server*.; I was confused why you were able to repro with google and msn which surely don't have latency around 20sec...

Comment: I am calling Sleep() in either case and it is to simulate latency.  It executes inline, but with the ThreadStarts, it executes concurrently on separate threads, thus total execution time does not exceed the max sleep time for the "slower" thread. I think that using small web requests is a poor way of testing this. Normally I use TPL for such things, say if I have a stored proc on 2 different DB servers that takes 3 mins to run, this code (using Tasks which I prefer) would help run it twice and still only use 3 minutes.

Comment: The problem with this is that the sleep method is not on the server, but rather, on the soap client. wrong solution to my problem.

Comment: I have however implemented this using threaded sync calls, and I get 3 seconds(total time of slower service) when debugging and 5 seconds(total time of both services) when running from IIS. any configuration I need to do?

Comment: The sleep is not part of the solution, it is to simulate long running web request. I really don't see the difference of where the sleep occurs, on client or server, since we are timing execution of a method (whatever it does). I think in your IIS scenario, you need to log the calls (individual and together) and see where the bottleneck is. It could be just taking longer to spin up the test site, for example. The difference between 3 and 5 seconds is not very big for SOAP requests. But I will create a simple asmx service that will sleep "on the server" and update my example.

Comment: The difference is that async only works if it never blocks. Only then it can be concurrent. And this is the case with a real async method. There is no thread being started to execute BeginXxx. A real BeginXxx *never has latency*.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin Its a school project. These are the requirements. 2 simple services with, one sleeps for 3 seconds, the other sleeps for 2 seconds. I have implemented the synchronous part that takes 5 seconds and the asynchronous works on the asp.net debug server but not iis. Is that clearer

Comment: @DavidKhaykin in your update, add the wait part. I need the total timespan to be equal to the slower service.

Comment: Ok, since I invested in this project already, I will do that and see if there are any specific config for asmx that might be causing it to delay. I think it's important to know the individual time for each request, because it could just be that with IIS there is spin up time added and the total time still reflects the "slower" service but because the times are so close to each other, it is difficult to tell. What I am hypothesizing is that the slower service just takes 5 seconds instead of 3 when run on IIS. Possibly. :)

Comment: Thanks.
Note, I have two methods. synchronous and asynchronous.
Respective results should be 5 and 3 seconds. I get that on the ASP.NET web server and I get 5 and 5 on IIS, exactly. So its not the spin up time (which sometimes occurs and takes it up to 5.9 or  6 or 7 seconds) :)

Comment: What version of IIS, by the way? And you place all 3 services in one site, with one app pool, or separate?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26094/discussion-between-bowofola-and-david-khaykin)

Answer (score 0):

There is some throttling in your system. Probably the service is configured for only one concurrent caller which is a common reason (WCF ConcurrencyMode). There might be HTTP-level connection limits (ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit) or WCF throttlings on the server.

Use Fiddler to determine if both requests are being sent simultaneously. Use the debugger to break on the server and see if both calls are running simultaneously.

Comment: its not a wcf. its an ASP.NET web service

Comment: Ok, did you check the other throttling possibilities? Did you use Fiddler and so on?

Comment: No not yet, Im not familiar with fiddler. But when i debug the application it works as expected. And i have now realized its an iis problem, probably something to do with the config or app pool but i know not what, yet.